# Directus 8 many-to-many not displaying

Tags: directus, headless-cms

I have a standard many-to-many table design with 'hosting' and 'months' connected by 'hosting-months'. In Directus 8 interface I set this up as:

[image]

I've tried multiple display settings, with the table name and without in dot (Twig?) format. 
`{{months.id}} - {{months.month}}` and `{{id}} - {{month}}`
However, whatever I try, when editing record in the collections view, it says No items selected (what I would expect if table is empty), but Add New and Select Existing are both empty.

[image]

and

[image]

In the end I just want to be able to assign multiple months here, such as January, April, July etc, and it seems like this is what it's designed to do. However I can't get any values to assign. And yes, my 'hosting' and 'months' table both have data.

DB structure is:

tbl hosting
-id
-domain
-cycle_start (not to store data, but seems like this is needed as field for many-to-many field in directus)

tbl months
-id
-month

tbl hosting_months
-id
-month_id
-hosting_id

Answer (score 1):

The display template is executed on the junction table, so you have to go a level "deeper". Try `{{month_id.id}} - {{month_id.month}}` instead.

Comment: Tried this, thanks, but it's still blank. I just added my db table structure to the end of my question above. 
Something I'm just missing. The collection I want the many-to-many in is the hosting table. I'm not sure what to expect from
the interface also, the add new and add existing are a little confusing. Are there any working examples out there?